# Matlab, matrix containing random numbers within specified range

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, range

I am absolutely new to Matlab and am trying to create an m-by-n matrix containing numbers within a specified range (ie. between -1 and 1).

Is there an equivalent function to `rand(m, n)` where I can specify the range myself or would I need to explicitely create a bunch of random numbers (as ie. was described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860823/generate-a-random-number-within-a-range)) and create a matrix from them?

Any pointers to relevant Documentation, etc. highly appreciated.

Comment: Matlab has great documentation. Next time try `help rand`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is straight from Matlab's documentation for `rand`. Is this want you want?

Example 1

Generate values from the uniform distribution on the interval [a, b]:

```
r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);
```

Try reading the Matlab documentation by entering `doc rand` in the command window. It is really informative and user friendly.

Comment: I did see this one, but this doesn't give a matrix (or am I doing sth wrong?), so would I need to create random numbers like this and then put it into a matrix myself or is there something that returns a matrix straight away?

Comment: That is strange. I just tried `A = -1 + 2*rand(5,5)` and I got a 5x5 matrix! The code written in the documentation (and my answer above) will give you a 100 x 1 vector.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, never mind my stupidity, I just realised what I did wrong...thx very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an easier way of doing that would be to type in

```
r = randi ( [a b], m , n )
```

where `a = -1` (or lower limit), `b = 1` (or upper limit), `m x n` as specified.  You might need to use `randint` if `randi`  doesn't work.

Comment: This only generates integer values, which doesn't seem to be what the OP wantes

Answer (score 1):

**6** *rand(4) => creates a 4x4 matrix with random numbers between 0 and **6**

**6** *rand(4,5) => creates a 4x5 matrix with random numbers between 0 and **6**

randi (**5**,3) => creates a 3x3 matrix with random integers between 0 and **5**

**2**+(**6**-2)*rand(3) => creates a 3x3 matrix with random numbers between **2** and **6**